# Sip2Peer. Trying to make bootstrap and Android example work --> numPeer is always 0 and list is empty

Tags: android, p2p, sip

I'm new with Sip2Peer and I was trying to set my Bootstrap Peer and SBC to use the Android example. I installed Apache Ant in my server and executed BootstrapPeer.java and SessionBorderController.java. When executing SBC the following warning appears:

```
WARNING: file "users.db" not found: created new empty DB
```

I used touch users.db to create it, I don't know if that's good or not.

Then I executed 2 emulators with the Sip2Peer application for Android and I executed it in my smartphone too. I configured them like this (both IP are the same, just hiding for security purpose):

```
Bootstrap Peer: bootstrap@147.83.XXX.XXX:5080
SCB Server: 147.83.XXX.XXX:6066
```

In my smartphone I didn't configure SBC since I'm using 3G connection, it's not behind a NAT. My two emulators are behind NAT, so I configured it. Then I clicked the SBC menu option in both emulators and sent a Join Message from all three devices.

When I do it in my emulators a Toast with the message "Received:peer_list" appears, but it doesn't in my smartphone. Is it because I didn't use SBC? I thought it wasn't needed if I wasn't behind a NAT.

The problem is that if I check the peer list it's always empty. I set some println in my Bootstrap file and in the following sentence of onReceivedJSONMsg:

```
//check the numPeerList field
int numPeer = (Integer) peerMsg.get("numPeerList");
```

this numPeer is always 0, so it nevers gets into the if clause. This are my log entrances:

```
{"sender":"peerDroid@10.0.2.XXX:50250","timestamp":1345816615658, "byte":218, "type":"recv", "typeMessage":"peer_join"}
{"sender":"peerDroid@10.178.51.XXX:50250","timestamp":1345816615658, "byte":223, "type":"recv", "typeMessage":"peer_join"}
{"timestamp":1345816650244, "receiver":"peerDroid@10.0.2.XXX:50250", "byte":"70", "transaction":"successful", "RTT":"7", "type":"sent", "typeMessage":"peer_list"}
{"timestamp":1345816650244, "receiver":"peerDroid@10.178.51.XXX:50250", "byte":"70", "transaction":"failed", "RTT":"7", "type":"sent", "typeMessage":"peer_list"}
```

If I try to send pings between my devices it works, I receive them, it's the list what's not working.

Does anybody know why it's not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should use different peer keys for different devices, so the bootstrap peer will treat all your devices as different peers.

You can change peer's key in `PeerActivity.init()` method.